# Confused about the effects of preceding-sibling and following-sibling

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm confused about what must be something basic, and previous questions (and the documentation) don't really help.

Say we have these 6 siblings:

```
<a_tag>... a1 ...</a_tag>
<b_tag>... b1 ...</b_tag>
<a_tag>... a2 ...</a_tag>
<b_tag>... b2 ...</b_tag>
<a_tag>... a3 ...</a_tag>
<b_tag>... b3 ...</b_tag>
```

Some xpath expressions work as I expect. For example, `//a_tag` selects all 3 `a_tags`; `//a_tag[2]` selects only `a2`.

Using `//a_tag[following-sibling::b_tag]` selects, again, all 3 `a_tags`.

Getting a little fancier, `//a_tag[following-sibling::b_tag[2]]` correctly selects `a1` and `a2`.  However, using `//a_tag[following-sibling::b_tag[3]]`, selects only `a1`, while I expected it to select all 3 `a_tags` (because they are all followed by `b_tag[3]`.

And then `//a_tag[preceding-sibling::b_tag[1]][following-sibling::b_tag[2]]` selects `a2`, as expected, but `//a_tag[preceding-sibling::b_tag[2]][following-sibling::b_tag[3]]`, which I expected to select `a3` comes up empty.

If you throw at it something which I would expect to select nothing, like `//a_tag[preceding-sibling::b_tag[2]][following-sibling::b_tag[1]]`, selects `a3` instead.

There are more like these, but I believe the problem is clear enough. Any light thrown on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Let me explain how this works.

```
//a_tag[following-sibling::b_tag[$n]]
```

In general language this means  *get me all `a_tag`s which have $n of following-siblings*.
Consider the below example:

> //a_tag[following-sibling::b_tag[1]]

This says get me all the `a_tag`s which have 1 `b_tag` after. Now, that all the `a_tag`s in the example have 1 `b_tag` after `a_tag`s, you will see all 3 `a_tag`s selected.

You will see only the first `a_tag` selected when used below xpath, because that's the only tag which have 3 `b_tag`s after.

> //a_tag[following-sibling::b_tag[3]]

---

Coming to the below xpath

> //a_tag[preceding-sibling::b_tag[1]][following-sibling::b_tag[2]]

When you have multiple conditions `[]` in xpath, it will execute from left to right meaning it will complete the left side condition then apply the next condition. So, the meaning of above xpath is *get me all `a_tag`s which have `b_tag`s 1 before and 2 after*, so `a2` is the only node which have `b1` (1 b_tag) before and `b2 and b3` (2 b_tags) after.

`//a_tag[preceding-sibling::b_tag[2]][following-sibling::b_tag[3]]` give you empty because you don't have `a_tag` which have 2 `b_tag`s before and 3 `b_tags` after.

Now you should under why `//a_tag[preceding-sibling::b_tag[2]][following-sibling::b_tag[1]]` selected `a3`.

Hope I am clear.

Comment: Clear as a bell. I thought the numbers inside the brackets were index numbers in the tree. Live and learn. Thanks (again) @supputuri.

Comment: You also need to be very careful with expressions like `//a_tag[2]`. It means `//descendant::node/child::a_tag[2]`, which selects every `a_tag` that is the second `a_tag` child of its parent node. It's worth studying the spec on this rather than assuming that intuition will give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> However, using `//a_tag[following-sibling::b_tag[3]]`, selects only `a1`, while I expected it to select all 3 `a_tags` (because they are all followed by `b_tag[3]`).

Here's how to adjust your model to match XPath's actual behavior:

- `//a_tag`

  - *Select all `a_tag` elements (as you mentioned)*.
- `//a_tag[following-sibling::b_tag[3]]`

  - *Of all selected `a_tag` elements, select only those **that have a third following sibling `b_tag` element,***  which is only the single `<a_tag>a1</a_tag>`, as observed.